# php Multiple emails being sent

Tags: php, email, gmail

I am using phpp to send eamils and I am getting multiple duplicate emails being sent to the email account, Here is the code I am using.

```
<?php 
//start mail out
    
set_time_limit(0); // this will keep the script from stopping if it takes longer then 30 seconds, must have this here
$emailaddress = array('nerja_fellowship_group@nerjabible.com', 'nerjabible1@gmail.com', 'nerjabible@gmail.com');
$emailsubject = "New messages added to the nerjabible website";
//$emailbody = file_get_contents(".email_out.html");
$fromaddress = "nerja_fellowship_group@nerjabible.com";
$i = count($emailaddress);
$z = 0;
     
// here we check how many email address's we have, if its is 0, then we don't start the email function
if ($i != 0)
{// start if
     
    // Lets loop until we reach the count from email address array
    while ($i != $z)
    {// start while
    
        // here we send the email to the varables from above, using the email array incrament
        if (mail($emailaddress[$z], $subject, $message, $headers))
            // mail($emailaddress[$z], $emailsubject, $message, "From: " .$fromaddress. "\nX-Mailer: PHP 4.x");
            // lets echo out that the email was sent
            echo $z + 1 . " out of " . $i . " emails sent. (" . $emailaddress[$z] . ")<br>";
     
        // increment the array one, so we get a new email address from the array
        ++$z;
    
    }// end while 
     
}//end if
     
else
{//start else
    
    // we echo out that no emails where found in the array and end the script
    echo "Warning: No emails in array.";
     
}// end else
echo "finished mails sent";
//end mail out
    
?>
```

I have tried this code on its own without any other code and I have even just sent

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{ 
    $answer = "Messages accepted";
}
else
{
    $answer = "Error: Messages not accepted";
}
```

I have also tried sending to my host account and various gmail accounts and I have tried wrapping the code in a for loop, all to no avail, I still get 3-6 duplicate emails to any account.

Comment: Learn to use `foreach()` instead of `for` or `while`. You'll thank me.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that will send duplicate emails. Something must be calling it twice.

Comment: Barmar, I tried for each with the same result, Just now I tried from my tablet, a different machine and got the same result

Comment: Why would foreach make a difference? That was just general advice, not a solution to the problem. As I said, there's nothing here that duplicates the email. Check your log to see if the code is being called twice.

Comment: The problem is solved the issue was caused by a line of code that created a loop and sent out multiple messages, it was not a problem with the attached mail send script.